# Set lighting intensity when using different scale than default

Tags: lighting, scale

Im making asset's for UE4, so i changed my start up pref. for scale to metric with a unit scale of 0.010000. The problem is with lighting, i have to turn it up to ridiculous strength and put the light right next to the object to get any effect. Is this normal, anything i can do to solve this, cheers in advance, sorry if this very obvious.

http://prntscr.com/jr8o2f

Comment: Why do you need lighting in blender to import models to UE4?

Comment: Yes it is normal. If things look good to you then the intensity is correct. Don't worry about using large or ridiculousl'y small values as long as you get what you want.